# What is the best way to import for optimizing code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Im currently using:

```
import os
```

Should I be importing everything separately like this:

```
from os import listdir, chdir, path, getcwd
```

I'm looking to get my compiled .exe as small in size and optimized as possible. Is it worth doing this or does python not include unused functions and classes when compiling?

Im using pyinstaller

Comment: If you try both, what is the difference in size of final .exe?

Comment: I doubt you will see any difference in resulting file size. Unlike `include` in C, `import` in Python doesn't actually copy-pastes code into the original file.

Comment: I don't think there will be difference in size of your exe. The two methods only change the how the functions are used.

Comment: Usually, it is not worth the effort trying to make the .exe as small as possible.

Comment: Python compiles to bytecode that's only then interpreted. When you import something, the whole library doesn't get copied over to your bytecode, it's just a way to bind names to external objects, which in turn will be interpreted themselves. Behind the scenes, there's no difference, performance or executable size wise, between `import os` and `from os import listdir`.

Comment: The only performance penalty you might find is if you import libraries you don't use. Then evaluating the code in that library makes your module that much slower.

Answer (score 1):

The `import os` method is more efficient in terms of execution time.

If we import the entire module:

```
import os

def list():
    print(os.listdir('.'))
```

it executes in 0.074s, but when importing one method only:

```
from os import listdir

def list():
    print(listdir('.'))
```

then it takes 0.076s.

Here I used the `timeit` module to time the execution of the above functions.

Comment: Consider completing your answer with information regarding how the different methods impact the size of the executable after compilation. However interesting, your answer does not address really Goli's question.

Comment: May be this time difference is because then you import one method, interpretator checks is where a such method in library.